# How can I use regex for all words beginning with : punctuation?

Tags: regex

How can I use regex for all words beginning with `:` punctuation?

This gets all words beginning with `a`:

```
\ba\w*\b
```

The minute I change the letter `a` to `:`, the whole thing fails. Am I supposed to escape the colon, and if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\b` matches between a non-alphanumeric and an alphanumeric character, so if you place it before `:`, it only matches if there is a letter/digit right before the colon.

So you either need to drop the `\b` here or specify what exactly constitutes a boundary in this situation, for example:

```
(?<!\w):\w*\b
```

That would ensure that there is no letter/digit/underscore right before the `:`. Of course this presumes a regex flavor that supports lookbehind assertions.

Comment: To be fair, this would capture the colon - presumably *not* what the OP intended

Comment: I don't know about that. He wants words beginning with `:`; I had assumed the colon is part of the word, but I agree specs are a bit hazy.

Comment: How is it possible for `\b` to match between both non-alphanumeric, and alphanumeric characters at the same time? That doesn't make any sense. Can't you just say that it matches all characters? Or that it matches all characters depending on whether the `\b` is at the left or right of the characters being matched?

Comment: It matches *the position between* (i. e. the empty space between) an alnum and a non-alnum (or vice versa), so it matches between `a` and `.` or between `<space>` and `1`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `\b` won't match the start of a word when the word starts with a colon `:`, because colon is **not** a word character. Try this:

```
(?<=:)\w*\b
```

This uses a (non-capturing) look-behind to assert that the previous character is a colon.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out when I tested it (then posted what I thought was the only answer at the time - no plagiarism intended)